# angular 1.6 unable to show scope value in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I have index.html

Previous

```
<body ng-app="MainController">
     <div class="page page-base {{ pageClass }}" ng-view>
     </div>
</div>
```

I assigned some values to $scope.errorMsg in registerController so changed
Changed to

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
     <div class="page page-base {{ pageClass }}" ng-view>
        <div ng-controller="MainController" ng-click="doClick($event)"></div>
        <div ng-controller="RegisterController"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In controller when I do console.log It print the value but it is not getting displayed on error.html page.

```
$scope.errorMsg = data.message;
$location.path("/reg/error");
```

I am new to Angular, Please let me know if I need to add in more info for my problem

Comment: how can your ng-app and ng-controller values be same. Please create a working demo replicating the issue a fiddle or plnkr. So that it easy to understand what is actually your problem.

Comment: No it's not same App name is myApp and controllers have their own names

Comment: You're changing the `path` as consequence your `scope` is destroyed.. you need to put this  `errorMsg` in `rootScope` in order to provide it in all `controllers`

Comment: you are adding ng logic inside a css class without the actual ng-class directive, you can't do that mate :)

Comment: Do you want to create a Plunkr with the code you have?

Comment: Please provide code in fiddle or Plnkr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) in the scope of RegisterController:

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterController">{{errorMsg}}</div>
```

**Update**

A common source of confusion to those new the angular is that scopes and controllers come and go with the wind, and it's not obvious where to place transient data.

Since angular services are singletons, one solution is to implement a service to store transient state - in the OPs case, "errorMsg" - among view changes.

Here's a bare bones singleton service.

```
app.factory('StateService', function() {
   // A singleton object to stuff transient data
   return { };
});
```

It's easily passed along to controller instances like so

```
app.controller('ErrorController', ['$scope', 'StateService', function($scope, states) { 
 . . .
});
```

[Here's a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VPwzqchuug9VZR5lcdKe?p=preview) that demonstrates the concept, using your code as a base.

Comment: @user269867 you can't access ```$scope.errorMsg``` at your new location, just try to assign to ```$rootScope.errorMsg``` and then get back to view, or use ```ui-router```

Comment: @MiguelLattuada you're on the right path with OP's problem I think (but a state service would be cleaner than mucking with $rootScope).

Comment: @RamblinRose Thank you for plunkr. I added the template for error inside my index.html and it kinds solve the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped.